# How to save a pointer to a base class to field of another class?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have 4 classes in my project: Base, Derived1, Derived2 and one more, for example MyClass.

I want to have a constructor like this

```
MyClass(Base *_p){p = _p};
```

p is a pointer to Base class, but it is really a pointer to Derived1 or Derived2.
Save a pointer to field is not safe: one can rewrite it from main.cpp and my programm will crash. What I mean:

```
Base *h = new Derived1();
MyClass d1 = MyClass(h);
*h = Derived2;
d1.run();
```

If we save h to a field of MyClass it will be something strange (we will use overloaded methods of Derived2 instead of Derived1) when we execute d1.run(). In d1.run() are used some overloaded methods of Base, for example p->insert(), which is different in Derived1 and Derived2.

So, I want to know, how should i write program in such case?

P.S. I still need help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  What does "Save a pointer to field is not safe: one can rewrite it from main.cpp and my programm will crash" mean?  It's probably best to add a complete example.

Comment: No, not really :(  What does `d1.run();` do?  What behaviour do you observe?

Comment: No It's not! What does `MyClass::run()` do? Is it virtual? Post a complete example, or at least classes declarations

Comment: It's ideological question, so I haven't ready programm.

Comment: You didn't spell out the role of "p" at all! Another point is that d1.run() - easier to analyze. You are operating with a derived class object directly. Please do add more details about the class hierarchy, even if you don't have a program that you are working with.

Comment: @KalyanS, you're right, I was too hurried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right you got something like

```
struct Base { 
             virtual void run () = 0; 
             virtual ~Base() {} };
struct Derived1 : Base { void run () { /* do Stuff A */ } };
struct Derived2 : Base { void run () { /* do Stuff B */ } };
struct MyClass { Base * p;
                MyClass (Base * _p) { p = _p; } };
```

Wehen you use `d1.run()` you won't see the method of `Derived2` being called.

```
Base *h = new Derived1();
MyClass d1 = MyClass(h); 
h = new Derived2(); // you change h here not d1.p !
// At this point d1.p is still the same value as above 
// pointing to the originally created Derived1 object
d1.run(); // will execute do Stuff A
```

---

Edit:

```
*h = Derived2; // Assignment
```

This assignment is only valid if `Derived1` either defines

- A constructor `Derived1 (Derived2 (const) &d2) { /*...*/}` or
- an assignment operator `Derived1& operator= (Derived2 (const) &d2) { /*...*/ }`

If this is the case and your main Program has any valid references or pointers to the structure  `d1.p` is pointing at then it can of course manipulate the logic.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I thought that if i change h in main.cpp it will be changed in d1.h. Sorry, my fault. Thx

Comment: Ah, Ok, that's not what I wanted to show. Now it's another example.